# Adaptive Icon shapes path

Tags: android, svg, android-launcher, android-icons, adaptive-icon

This is how **Launcher3** defines icon shape path.

```
<string-array translatable="false" name="icon_shape_override_paths_values">
    <item>M50,0L100,0 100,100 0,100 0,0z</item>
    <item>M50,0 C10,0 0,10 0,50 0,90 10,100 50,100 90,100 100,90 100,50 100,10 90,0 50,0 Z</item>
    <item>M50 0A50 50,0,1,1,50 100A50 50,0,1,1,50 0</item>
    <item>M50,0A50,50,0,0 1 100,50 L100,85 A15,15,0,0 1 85,100 L50,100 A50,50,0,0 1 50,0z</item>
</string-array>
```

These correspond to square, squircle, circle and teardrop accordingly.

Now I wonder how can I create my own shape like this. I want to draw a hexagon.

Comment: Are you asking how to draw a hexagon, or how to add the shape to Launcher3?

Comment: @PaulLeBeau how to draw in this manner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
<item>M 50,0 L 100,25, 100,75, 50,100, 0,75, 0,25 Z</item>
```

Example:

```css
svg {
  background: linen;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <path d="M 50,0 L 100,25, 100,75, 50,100, 0,75, 0,25 Z"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: can I ask you how did you draw it, for example can I do same with inkscape?

Comment: I just did it manually in the editor.  `M` is moveto, `L` is for lines. The other shapes are based on a 100x100 square, so I just experimented with the Y coordinates on the left and right sides (ie. 25 and 75) until the hexagon shape looked okay.  No need for Inkscape here as it is a very simple shape. But yes, you could use Inkscape if you wanted to.